# Java spec changed for AND OR operator precedence?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, specifications, operator-precedence

i have been studying for Oracle java certification exam for a while.

today i came across a question asking which part of expression evaluates.

it was sth like  **a() || b() && c().**

so far everything seems ok. && operator precedence has higher priority then || operator and it evaluates first and then || operator evaluates.

the problem arises when i try to run similar code on my windows 7/java 7 machine.  when i run my code the || operator evalautes first. I checked a few books, and the one i study(manning java associate prep.)  it says vice versa.  what do you think whats wrong?

here is my code you can check

```
public class Dummy {


public static  void main(String[] arg) {

boolean ax = method1() ||  method2()  &&  method3() ;
```

}

```
public static boolean method1(){

System.err.println("method1");

return false;
}

public static boolean method2(){

System.err.println("method2");
return false;
}

public static boolean method3(){
System.err.println("method3");
return true;
}
```

}

Edit : what i get as output : method1 , method 2
What i expect : method2 , method1

**edit 2: this is what the book says (manning OCA java Se 7 programmer 1 cert. guide) page 507**

The expression (a >= 99 || a <= 33 && b == 10) has three operands together with
the OR(||) and AND(&&) short-circuit operators.

**Because the short-circuit operator AND has higher operator precedence than the short-circuit operator OR, the expression is evaluated as follows:
(a >= 99 || (a <= 33 && b == 10))
Evaluation of the preceding expression starts with the evaluation of (a <= 33 && b == 10).**

Because a <= 33 evaluates to true, the operator && evaluates the second operand (b == 10)
to determine whether (a <= 33 && b == 10) will return trueor false. a <= 33returns true
and b == 10 returns false, so the expression (a <= 33 && b == 10)returns false.
The original expression—(a >= 99 || (a <= 33 && b == 10)) is now reduced to the
following expression:
(a >= 99 || false)

The short-circuit operator OR(||) executes its first operand (even if the value of the
second operand is known), evaluating a >= 99. So for this expression, all three oper-ands are evaluated.....

Comment: Operator precedence has nothing to do with execution order. It only controls argument grouping.

Comment: I edited the question now it includes output.

Comment: *"Java spec changed for AND OR operator precedence?"*.  No.

Comment: i edited again and pasted what book says, so its wrong as i understand from what u have said

Comment: The book is incorrect.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah you are right, i checked your answer. the book confused me. if you paste your answer, i will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` operator is handled before the `||`, but the operands are evaluated before any operator handling.

[Section 15.7.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) states:

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

So, `method1()` and `method2()` are evaluated before `||` or `&&` operate.  The `&&` short-circuits, so `method3()` is not called.  Then `&&` operates, yielding `false`, then `||` operates, yielding `false`.

This is printed:

```
method1
method2
```

Comment: @user3580294 The `||` operator evaluates its operands -- `method1()` and `method2() && method3()`.  `method1()` prints `method1` and returns `false`.  Then the `&&` operator evaluates its operands -- `method2()` prints `method2` and returns `false`, and `&&` short-circuits and yields `false`.  Then the `||` operator operates and yields `false`.

Comment: Oh right, seems like I'm getting my precedence mixed up -- thought higher precedence went later for some inexplicable reason. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just got confused.

They are executed like this.

`method1() ||  (method2()  &&  method3());`

Your `method1` returns false, it is evaluated first (as we have left to right here). Then `method2` is evaluated and returns false. And finally it makes no sense to evaluate `method3`, the result of the whole && is already known to be false. Finally, false || false gives false. This is the final result and `method3` was not even evaluated to reach to this result.

Comment: i edited again and pasted what the book says about it, i am confused :)